# Pandas groupby mean() not ignoring NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

If I calculate the mean of a groupby object and within one of the groups there is a NaN(s) the NaNs are ignored. Even when applying np.mean it is still returning just the mean of all valid numbers. I would expect a behaviour of returning NaN as soon as one NaN is within the group. Here a simplified example of the behaviour

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,np.nan,2,3],'b':[1,2,1,2]})
c.groupby('b').mean()
     a
b     
1  1.5
2  3.0
c.groupby('b').agg(np.mean)
     a
b     
1  1.5
2  3.0
```

I want to receive following result:

```
     a
b     
1  1.5
2  NaN
```

I am aware that I can replace NaNs beforehand and that i probably can write my own aggregation function to return NaN as soon as NaN is within the group. This function wouldn't be optimized though.

Do you know of an argument to achieve the desired behaviour with the optimized functions?

Btw, I think the desired behaviour was implemented in a previous version of pandas.

Comment: This behavior of Pandas is dreadful... None of the solutions proposed make standard functions like `np.mean()` work as it should (returning NaN)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, `pandas` skips the `Nan` values. You can make it include `Nan` by specifying `skipna=False`:

```
In [215]: c.groupby('b').agg({'a': lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False)})
Out[215]: 
     a
b     
1  1.5
2  NaN
```

Answer (score 14):

## There is `mean(skipna=False)`, but it's not working

GroupBy aggregation methods (min, max, mean, median, etc.) have the `skipna` parameter, which is meant for this exact task, but it seems that currently (may-2020) there is a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32696) (issue opened on mar-2020), which prevents it from working correctly.

## Quick workaround

Complete working example based on this comments: [@Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54106817/7204581), [@RoelAdriaans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106112/pandas-groupby-mean-not-ignoring-nans/54106520#comment104906560_54106817)

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,np.nan,2,3],'b':[1,2,1,2]})
>>> c.fillna(np.inf).groupby('b').mean().replace(np.inf, np.nan)

     a
b     
1  1.5
2  NaN
```

For additional information and updates follow the link above.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `skipna` option -

```
c.groupby('b').apply(lambda g: g.mean(skipna=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use a *value* that is not ignored by default, for example `np.inf`:

```
>>> c = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,np.inf,2,3],'b':[1,2,1,2]})
>>> c.groupby('b').mean()
          a
b          
1  1.500000
2       inf
```

Comment: Before the mean calculation you can use `fillna(np.inf)` and after the mean you can use `.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` to restore the nan values.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different methods for it:

1. **slowest**:

```
    c.groupby('b').apply(lambda g: g.mean(skipna=False))
```

2. **faster than apply but slower than default sum**:

```
    c.groupby('b').agg({'a': lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False)})
```

3. **Fastest but need more codes**:

```
    method3 = c.groupby('b').sum()
    nan_index = c[c['b'].isna()].index.to_list()
    method3.loc[method3.index.isin(nan_index)] = np.nan
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I landed here in search of a fast (vectorized) way of doing this, but did not find it. Also, in the case of complex numbers, `groupby` behaves a bit strangely: it doesn't like `mean()`, and with `sum()` it will convert groups where all values are `NaN` into `0+0j`.

So, here is what I came up with:

**Setup**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 1, 2],
    'b': [1, np.nan, 2, 3],
    'c': [1, np.nan, 2, np.nan],
    'd': np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan]) * 1j,
})
gb = df.groupby('a')
```

**Default behavior**:

```
gb.sum()

Out[]:
     b    c                   d
a                              
1  3.0  3.0  0.000000+2.000000j
2  3.0  0.0  0.000000+0.000000j
```

**A single `NaN` kills the group**:

```
cnt = gb.count()
siz = gb.size()
mask = siz.values[:, None] == cnt.values
gb.sum().where(mask)

Out[]:
     b    c   d
a              
1  3.0  3.0 NaN
2  NaN  NaN NaN
```

**Only `NaN` if all values in group are `NaN`**:

```
cnt = gb.count()
gb.sum() * (cnt / cnt)
out

Out[]:
     b    c                   d
a                              
1  3.0  3.0  0.000000+2.000000j
2  3.0  NaN                 NaN
```

**Corollary: mean of complex**:

```
cnt = gb.count()
gb.sum() / cnt

Out[]:
     b    c                   d
a                              
1  1.5  1.5  0.000000+2.000000j
2  3.0  NaN                 NaN
```